# SAP HANA Vora 1.2 : Cannot load as virtual table in HANA Studio

Tags: hana, vora

In SAP HANA Vora 1.2 Dev Edition: I've configured the Spark Controller and started server. Then I run the spark-shell and created a new table. In SAP HANA Studio i can see now folder "spark_velocity" and "table001" in it, which I created. When I try to add this table my HANA folder with "Add as Virtual Table" option I receive an error:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [476]: invalid remote object name: Unable to retrieve
>   remote metadata for
>   SparkSQL.spark_velocity.SparkSQL.spark_velocity.table001: line 0 col 0
>   (at pos 0)

And here is full Exception:

```
com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.JDBCDriverException: SAP DBTech JDBC: [476]: invalid remote object name: Unable to retrieve remote metadata for SparkSQL.spark_velocity.SparkSQL.spark_velocity.table001: line 0 col 0 (at pos 0)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.createException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:345)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionSapDB.generateDatabaseException(SQLExceptionSapDB.java:185)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.packet.ReplyPacket.buildExceptionChain(ReplyPacket.java:102)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.execute(ConnectionSapDB.java:1031)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.ConnectionSapDB.execute(ConnectionSapDB.java:820)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.sendCommand(StatementSapDB.java:898)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.sendSQL(StatementSapDB.java:947)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.execute(StatementSapDB.java:256)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.StatementSapDB.executeUpdate(StatementSapDB.java:417)
    at com.sap.db.jdbc.trace.Statement.executeUpdate(Statement.java:218)
    at com.sap.ndb.studio.federation.services.ds.impl.sql.FederationSQLService.executeUpdate(FederationSQLService.java:212)
    at com.sap.ndb.studio.federation.services.ds.impl.sql.FederationSQLService.createProxyTable(FederationSQLService.java:1156)
    at com.sap.ndb.studio.federation.services.ds.impl.sql.DataProvisioningService.createProxyTable(DataProvisioningService.java:421)
    at com.sap.ndb.studio.federation.catalog.job.AddAsProxyJob.run(AddAsProxyJob.java:135)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this issue when incompatible versions were used. With Vora 1.2 you need Spark Controller 1.5 Patch 5 (HANASPARKCTRL00P_5-70001262.RPM) and HANA SPS11. Also make sure to configure the Spark Controller with the Vora1.2 datasources jar (spark-sap-datasources-1.2.33-assembly.jar).