# Cannot create virtual table using HANA Studio

Tags: hana, vora

In SAP HANA Vora 1.2 on MapR 5.1/Spark 1.5.2 with Spark Controller 1.6 PL1:

I've configured the Spark Controller and started server. Successfully loaded the table and can be seen from VORA tools.

In SAP HANA Studio I can see now folder "`spark_velocity`" and "`M_JCUST`" in it, which I created. When I try to add this table my HANA folder with "Add as Virtual Table" option I receive an error:

> SAP DBTech JDBC: [476]: invalid remote object name:
>
> Unable to retrieve remote metadata for SparkSQL.spark_velocity.SparkSQL.spark_velocity.M_JCUST: line 0 col 0 (at pos 0)

`/var/log/hanaes` is below:

```
16/11/01 20:11:37 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/11/01 20:11:37 INFO DefaultSource: Creating VoraRelation M_JCUST using an existing catalog table
16/11/01 20:11:37 INFO Utils: freeing the buffer
16/11/01 20:11:37 ERROR HanaVoraCatalog: Exception occurred in Lookup Relation
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.BaseRelationSource cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sq
l.sources.BaseRelation
        at org.apache.spark.sql.vora.hana.HanaVoraCatalog.getTableRelation(HanaVoraCatalog.scala:27)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.hana.CompositeCatalog$class.getTableRelation(HanaDBCatalog.scala:99)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.hana.HanaSimpleCatalog.getTableRelation(SparkCatalog.scala:44)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.hana.HanaSQLContext.getTableMetaNew(HanaSQLContext.scala:337)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.handleMessage(CommandRouter.scala:516)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anon$1.run(CommandRouter.scala:272)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anon$1.run(CommandRouter.scala:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1575)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(CommandRouter.scala:270)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.aroundReceive(CommandRouter.scala:231)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
:
16/11/01 20:11:37 ERROR CommandHandler:
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.hana.HanaSQLContext.getTableMetaNew(HanaSQLContext.scala:347)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.handleMessage(CommandRouter.scala:516)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anon$1.run(CommandRouter.scala:272)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anon$1.run(CommandRouter.scala:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1575)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(CommandRouter.scala:270)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.aroundReceive(CommandRouter.scala:231)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
16/11/01 20:11:37 ERROR RequestOrchestrator: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.hive.hana.HanaSQLContext.getTableMetaNew(HanaSQLContext.scala:347)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.handleMessage(CommandRouter.scala:516)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anon$1.run(CommandRouter.scala:272)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2$$anon$1.run(CommandRouter.scala:270)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1575)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler$$anonfun$receive$2.applyOrElse(CommandRouter.scala:270)
        at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
        at com.sap.hana.spark.network.CommandHandler.aroundReceive(CommandRouter.scala:231)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
        at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
        at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

This issue is same issue as posted below:
[SAP HANA Vora 1.2 : Cannot load as virtual table in HANA Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37045599/sap-hana-vora-1-2-cannot-load-as-virtual-table-in-hana-studio)

But,  I use SAP HANA SPS12, Spark Controller 1.6 PL1 with MapR Support and replaced spark-sap-datasources-1.2.33-assembly.jar correctly.

Any advice on this error ?

Thanks and regards
Mana

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue due to an incompatibility between Spark Controller 1.6.1 PL1 and Spark 1.5.2. It is currently planned to address this issue in the next Spark Controller version (Subject to change)